# Azure DevOps pushed branch from GitHub closed and added links to 600+ tasks. How do I undo changes I did in 2 minutes?

Tags: github, azure-devops, git-push

I have created a repo in Azure DevOps and pushed the master branch of a big repo from GitHub.

The commits have had those commands to close tasks and add links. As result I have closed and added links to many tasks. God knows what else I did in 2 minutes. In total I have updated 641 tasks, user stories and features across the whole organisation. How do I undo the changes I did in these 2 minutes automatically?

Update. It seems I just added links. For now I just walked through the epics & features & removed, the rest for now left as is. May be will find automatic way to undo.